# $f(a)=f(b)=\lambda,\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}<0\implies f(x)>\lambda \forall x\in(a,b)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $y=f(x)$ be a smooth function in $[a,b]$ such that :

$$f(a)=f(b)=\lambda,\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}<0$$

then, we need to prove that :

$$f(x)>\lambda \forall x\in(a,b)$$

I observed this by graphical intuition. By inspection , the result written is the only case possible. Consider the graph below for $x\in[0,4]$ as an illustration :

[image: EXAMPLE]

I couldn't imagine any other type of graph possible following above properties except of this type. My question is : how can I approach to prove it rigorously ?

Comment: The graph of a concave function lies above the secant between two points – look at the first illustration here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function

Comment: This is a special case of [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

Comment: I agree with @MartinR ... a calculus course will include a "second-derivative criterion" for convex and for concave functions.  [Some texts may use terms "concave up" and "concave down" for some reason.]

Comment: As written, the statement isn't true. You have $f(x)>\lambda$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, which would include $x=a$ and $x=b$, but we have $f(a)=f(b)=\lambda$. I think what we want is $f(x)>\lambda$ for all $x\in (a,b)$.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes I know what a concave up and concave down function is. But I want to prove it by equations and not by just having an intuitive vision.

Comment: @user114263 sorry I'll correct it.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks sir. How can I proceed to prove it ? Unfortunately, my calculus is very weak so I don't know what is jensen inequality.

Comment: @ActuallyFritz I'll read the article. Thanks, it's useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way.  Mean value theorem.

Assume $f(a) = f(b) = \lambda$ and $f''(x) < 0$.  Fix $c$ with $a<c<b$.  Assume (for purposes of contradiction) $f(c)\le\lambda$.  By the mean value theorem, there is $r$ with $a<r<c$ with
$$
f'(r) = \frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a} \ge 0 .
$$
Similarly, there is $s$ with $c<s<b$ with $f'(s)\le0$.  Then apply the mean value theorem on the interval $[r,s]$ to conclude there is $t$ with $r<t<s$ where
$$
f''(t) = \frac{f'(s)-f'(r)}{s-r} \ge 0,
$$
a contradiction.

Comment: This shows that $f(x)\geqslant \lambda$ for $x\in(a,b)$, not that $f(x)>\lambda$ for $x\in (a,b)$.

Comment: I will fix.....

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $f$ is **strictly** does constitute a rigorous proof of what you want. But let's see why.

We are assuming $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f'$ is differentiable, and therefore also continuous, on $(a,b)$.

Assume there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)\leqslant \lambda$. By the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $\xi\in (a,c)$ such that $$f'(\xi)=\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a} =\frac{f(c)-\lambda}{c-a}\leqslant \frac{\lambda-\lambda}{c-a}=0.$$  By the Mean Value Theorem again, there exists $\zeta\in(c,b)$ such that $$f'(\zeta)=\frac{f(b)-f(c)}{b-c}=\frac{\lambda-f(c)}{b-c}\geqslant \frac{\lambda-\lambda}{b-c}=0.$$

So there exists a point $\xi\in(a,c)$ such that $f'(\xi)\leqslant 0$ and there exists a point $\zeta\in(c,b)$ such that $f'(\zeta)\geqslant 0$. By the Mean Value Theorem applied to $f'$ on $[\xi,\zeta]$, there exists $\phi\in(\xi,\zeta)\subset (a,b)$ such that $$f''(\psi)=\frac{f'(\zeta)-f'(\xi)}{\zeta-\xi}\geqslant \frac{0-0}{\zeta-\xi}=0,$$ a contradiction of our assumption that $f''(x)<0$ for $x\in (a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $d^2y/dx^2 \lt 0$ implies that $dy/dx$ is Strictly Decreasing.

Then Integral of $f''(x)$ , which is $f'(x)+C_1$ , has some value at $x=a$ & that keep reducing when moving towards $x=b$.

In Case $f'(a)$ & $f'(b)$ are Positive , Area Under Curve will be Positive & Increasing (in magnitude) from $x=a$ to $x=b$.
In Case $f'(a)$ & $f'(b)$ are Negative , Area Under Curve will be Negative & Increasing (in magnitude) from $x=a$ to $x=b$.

Only when $f'(a)$ is Positive & $f'(b)$ is Negative , then we will have Area Under Curve Positive Increasing (in magnitude) from $x=a$ to $x=c$ where $f'(c)=0$ for some $c \in (a,b)$ & then the Positive Area will reduce from $x=c$ to $x=b$.
We want Integral of $f'(x)$ , which is $f(x)+C_2$ , to have $f(a)=\lambda$. Then we can see that it will increase from $x=a$ to $x=c$ & then it has to reduce from $x=c$ to $x=b$ , where we have $f(b)=\lambda$.
There is a Single Maxima at $x=c$ by Mean Value Theorem or Rolle Theorem or other related theorems.
Everywhere , we have $f(x) \gt \lambda$

Visualization :

[image: Visualization]

The Blue Curves are the Integral curves for $f''(x)$ , which are the Strictly Decreasing $f'(x)+C_1$ curves.
The Area Under Curve is Positive for the upper curve & Negative for lower curve.
Only the middle curve can have $0$ Area Under Curve.
The Area Under Curve , which is $f(x)+C_2$ , will Maxima $x=c$ to give the $\lambda$ values at $x=a$ & $x=b$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that is admittedly overkill, but is a different perspective that I think is neat.

We know that if $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ is an open, bounded, simply connected set, and if $\phi\in C(\bar\Omega)\cap C^2(\Omega)$ is **superharmonic**, which means
$$-\Delta \phi\geq 0\Longleftrightarrow \Delta\phi\leq 0$$

That it obeys the "*minimum principle*":

$$\min_{\bar\Omega}\phi=\min_{\partial\Omega}\phi$$
Which means, the minimum of $\phi$ must be attained on the boundary. This follows from the fact that $$\phi(x)\geq \boldsymbol{-\kern-11.2pt}\int_{\mathbb B(x,r)}\phi~\mathrm d\mu^n$$
For all $\mathbb B(x,r)\subseteq\Omega$.

---

Letting $\Omega=(a,b)$ in $\mathbb R^1$ this means $\min_{[a,b]}f=\min_{\{a,b\}}f=\min(f(a),f(b))=\lambda$, in other words $f(x)\geq \lambda ~~\forall x\in (a,b)$.